# percolate:synced-cron shows only 2 records all the time

Tags: node.js, meteor, cron

I am using *Meteor 1.5* and package *percolate:synced-cron* to run a task every day once. After some days I noticed that my previous records inside "*cronHistory*" collection got automatically deleted (without me personally deleting the records), and shows only past 2 days history.

I am not sure what is wrong with the **cronHistory** collection. Any suggestions would be deeply apprciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to do a little research yourself and read the docs of packages you use. Even better, read the source to understand what kind of code you accept into your codebase. From the docs:

```
  SyncedCron.config({
    ...

    /*
      TTL in seconds for history records in collection to expire
      NOTE: Unset to remove expiry but ensure you remove the index from
      mongo by hand

      ALSO: SyncedCron can't use the `_ensureIndex` command to modify
      the TTL index. The best way to modify the default value of
      `collectionTTL` is to remove the index by hand (in the mongo shell
      run `db.cronHistory.dropIndex({startedAt: 1})`) and re-run your
      project. SyncedCron will recreate the index with the updated TTL.
    */
    collectionTTL: 172800
  });
```

Note the `collectionTTL` option is set to 2 days.

Comment: I agree i was little rushing to use the code. I will try to take care from here.